RuntimeWarning in scipy.stats.kstest for very small samples
I want to explore the possibility of using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit test to determine whether an array of experimental data fits an array of previously defined theoretical expectations.
To try and see how the predefined scipy.stats.kstest() function works, I did the following:
import scipy.stats as stats
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[2,3,3,4,6]
stat,p=stats.kstest(a,b,alternative='two-sided')

The output is:
RuntimeWarning: ks_2samp: Exact calculation unsuccessful. Switching to method=asymp.
return ks_2samp(xvals, yvals, alternative=alternative, method=method)

I don't understand the reason behind the RuntimeWarning. After investigating the issue a bit, I found out that the second argument has to be a callable and not an array of expected values... is there any way to make it work like I was trying to here?

Not sure, but my first guess is that the callable is supposed to be a pdf or cdf for a distribution. To work your problem into that template, maybe construct an empirical distribution from the array -- I think there's probably a scipy.stats function for that. However, I don't know how meaningful any such test is going to be. You know a priori that any actual sample cannot exactly fit a theoretical distribution, therefore whether a significance test says reject or don't reject depends entirely on how big your sample is.

With a large enough sample, you are almost certain to reject the null hypothesis. This isn't very useful; a more practical approach is to look at how far from theory the observed data are. This is a so-called "effect size" analysis. A web search for that term will find some resources. Note that this problem isn't specific to KS tests but is a well-known problem with significance tests in general.

K-S test does not apply to distributions with many ties as you have in your example. See: Is Kolmogorov-Smirnov test valid with discrete distributions? - Cross Validated

If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on Cross Validated Stack Exchange, where statistical analysis is on-topic.

You may try with ks_2samp, like the following ..
stat, p = stats.ks_2samp(a, b, alternative='two-sided')

Sadly, I get the same result, and the same warning. Apparently it's already using ks_2samp by default when it detects that b is not a callable, but an array :(
